# Load CSS and JS Files in Express

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, static

Let's say I have a node.js with Express project with the following directory:

```
server.js
package.json
views
   index.ejs
   css
      style.css
   js
      script.js
   video
      vid.mp4
   img
      bg.png
```

When I try to run this project my index.ejs shows up, but the rest of the files in the views folder don't show up. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));`

Comment: Please put that as an answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use static() method in express

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));`